# command-line-argument deduction as a special variable

Tags: regex, perl

My simple script in **Perl**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl                                            
use v5.20.1;                                               
use strict;                                                
use warnings;                                              

$| = 1;                                                    

my $string     = $ARGV[ 0 ];                               
my $match      = $ARGV[ 1 ];                               
my $substitute = $ARGV[ 2 ];                               

$string =~ m/match/g; # just for capturing the pattern                                     

$string =~ s/$match/only $substitute/g;                    

say "\$1[itself]  == $1";                                  
say "\$substitute == $substitute";                         
say "\$string     == $string";                             
say "prefix      == $`";                                   
say "match       == $&";                                   
say "suffix      == $'";
```

**Input and Output:**

```
$ perl temp 'I have 9 dollars' '(\d+)' '$1'
$1[itself]  == 9
$substitute == $1
$string     == I have only $1 dollars
prefix      == I have 
match       == 9
suffix      == dollars
```

A thing that I am trying to do is a simple **substitution** by initializing the **match** and **substitution** variable from **@ARGV**. After that a simple **match** for **initializing** the special character such as **$1**. But when I want to pass the special character `$1` from `command-line` to the script, it is deducted as a **regular string** and not the special variable **$1** that I need for **substitution**

If I change the code from:

```
$string =~ s/$match/only $substitute/g;
```

to:

```
$string =~ s/$match/only $1/g;
```

now it works!
**1. Why `$1` of the command line is different from `$1` in the script?**
**2. Is there any way to solve it?**

A screenshot of my console:

[image]

---

### Edit

As [ikegami](https://stackoverflow.com/users/589924/ikegami) suggested I installed and used the [String::Substitution](http://search.cpan.org/dist/String-Substitution/lib/String/Substitution.pm) and could by using `gsub_copy($line, $match, $substitute);` deduced the **substitution**.
But still I need to use this **substitution** itself for printing it on the screen and colorize it for illustration that what happens.
In fact this purpose, is part of a **rename** script that read all file and by call `rename` function, changes the name of the files.

As you can see on the screenshot:

[image]

instead of `for_$1` it should be `for_Level` on the screen. So **does this module can return what it has deduced?**
I am not talking about the **sub match** of the **match group parentheses**!
Also the author of the module has said:

> This module does not save or interpolate $& to avoid the "considerable
>   performance penalty"

May this screenshot clarify the subject:

[image]

Comment: Try `$string =~ s/$match/"\"only $substitute\""/gee` (Though you should never eval user input like this, it is not safe)

Comment: @HåkonHægland, Hi. It works. Please wait so that I test it in my main script then you can put your answer. thanks

Comment: @k-five, No, HH's solution doesn't work. Try `perl temp 'I have 9 dollars' '(\d+)' '"$1"'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Why $1 of the command line is different from $1 in the script?*

You're actually asking why

```
s/.../...$substitute.../
```

in your script is different than

```
s/.../...$1.../
```

in your script. For the same reason that

```
print($substitute);
```

is different than

```
print($1);
```

and that is that the value of `$1` (the captured text) is different than the value of `$substitute` (`$1`).

---

This is what you need:

```
use String::Substitution qw( gsub_modify );

gsub_modify($string, $match, $substitue);
```

That assumes you don't actually need `$1` outside of the replacement expression, and that you don't actually need `$&` and friends at all. If you do need them, then you can use the following:

```
use String::Substitution qw( interpolate_match_vars last_match_vars );

$string =~ s/$match/ interpolate_match_vars($substitute, last_match_vars()) /eg;
```

Comment: Apart from using **$1** I still need to use `$&` and `prefix` and `suffix` too. in my main script. **First** with this module that I installed just now, if I can access these **special variable**. **Second** is it safe? because the main purpose of my script is for **renaming** name of the lots of files. Tell me here or may you would like **update** the answer. no problem. I am trying this module now. **Thanks**.

Comment: Yes, it's safe. I didn't check personally, but that's the whole point of the module.

Comment: Sorry @ikegami, still does not work as I want. **May** my idea is wrong at all and I should change it. [Test](https://gist.github.com/k-five/42f5fdb3fbade84732ab25373a6dea3f) and also [the main predefined](https://gist.github.com/k-five/abcb2414baab0c04b62a387aabb5c247) I apologize for bothering you. If it is not a good idea feel free, tellme and ignore it.

Comment: Use `perl temp 'I have 3 dollars' '(\d+)' '$1'` instead of `perl temp 'I have 3 dollars' '(\d+)' '$&'`

Comment: As `my $string_2 = gsub_copy($string, $match, $substitute);` should be `my $string_2 = s/$match/ interpolate_match_vars($substitute, last_match_vars()) /reg;`

Comment: `Use of uninitialized value $string in concatenation (.) or string at temp line ...`  is the **error.** Many thanks and again sorry. I just ignore the **colorize** output. The second answer to me have said: `don't do this. Basically this is just running eval on ...`. I am **curious** what is it. I read a little about **Perl** but never heard that before. Please give a link to read information about it. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Obligatory discouragement: don't do this. Basically this is just running `eval` on a user-supplied string, which is really a bad idea.

Actual answer: use the `ee` modifer (see [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#s%2fPATTERN%2fREPLACEMENT%2fmsixpodualngcer)) to `s///` to `eval` the string in the right hand part of the expression:

```
$string =~ s/$match/"\"only $substitute\""/gee
```

By the way, you don't need to capture the pattern separately, just put the `$match` in a capturing group in the `s///` expression:

```
$string =~ s/($match)/"\"only $substitute\""/gee
```

Comment: No, your answer says it's a bad idea but do it anyway.

Comment: @ikegami Yes- I discourage using `eval`, but still show the OP how to do it. As long as this is just for personal use, `eval` is not necessarily evil.

Comment: Do not argue. I just doing some tests. If it it breaks some rule and safety I **never** use it.

Comment: You are mistaken. This use of eval IS "evil" (though I prefer the term "buggy"). For example, `perl temp 'I have 9 dollars' '(\d+)' '"$1"'`